# hide/show option in select using jQuery UI selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am using the jquery selectmenu plugin to display a nicely style select menu. I have three select menus, all options are hidden in the last two menus, when you select an option from menu one it shows the relevant options in menu two. The same thing happens for menu the two to three. Without the selectmenu plugin this works fine. Unfotunately with the select menu plugin it disapears and doesn't reappear.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/GXtpC/1525/

```
$(function(){            
    $('select').selectmenu({
        style:'popup'
    });

    $('.select1').on('change', function () {
        var parentId = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        $('.all-opt').hide();
        $('.' + parentId).show();
    });
    $('.select2').on('change', function () {
        var parentIdReg = $(this).children(":selected").attr("data-id");
        $('.select3-option').hide();
        $('.' + parentIdReg).show();
    });

});
```

Fully working without jQuery selectmenu plugin

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/GXtpC/1526/

Comment: This happens because the `selectmenu` widget replaces most of your html (including the `id` and `data-id` attributes). It's expected behaviour. How have you tried to work around this and what problems do you have with it? (side note: `style` is not a valid option)

Comment: You can find the new appended element when it has id. For example when you have `$('#myspecialselect').selectmenu();`, the new element is `$("#myspecialselect-menu")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `selectmenu()` widget, but I can point point to some things to note. Modifying your code a little, it seems like after calling the `selectmenu()`, it makes calling `hide()` not possible:

```
$(function(){            
    $('.select1').selectmenu();
    $('.select3').selectmenu();

    $('.select2').hide();    <---- hidden
    $('.select3').hide();    <---- not hidden
/*
    $('.select1').on('change', function () {
       ...
       ...
    */
});
```

Also, a slight typo in the form caused

```
SELECT OPTION 1
SELECT OPTION 1
SELECT OPTION 3
```

I suppose it should be 1,2 and 3?

Comment: This is due to `selectmenu` replacing the `select` element with a `div` element and wiping out the `class` in the process; it's not `hide()` that's at fault but the selector matching nothing

Comment: I'm still struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
// init
var mySelect = $( "#my-select" ).selectmenu();

// hide
mySelect.selectmenu('close');
mySelect.widget().hide();

// show
mySelect.widget().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, which I solved calling

`$( "#original_select_id" ).selectmenu( "refresh" );`

I had code which removed or appended select options based on selection of other select. IE have problems with show/hide method for select options, that is why I use remove/append method instead (maybe this is required for the provided code to solve this problem).

With this code executing after the changes in the original select element was done, the jQuery UI selectmenu "reinitialized" itself and contains only options that was added / not removed on the fly.